# verify $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i)^2 + \frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(a_ib_j - a_j b_i)^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2) (\sum_{j=1}^nb_j^2)$

Tags: real-analysis

> (Exercise 1.1.5 in Real Analysis 2 by Terence Tao) Let $n\ge1$, and let $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ and $b_1,b_2, ..., b_n$ be real numbers. Verify the identity
>   $$(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ib_i)^2 + \frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(a_ib_j - a_j b_i)^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2) (\sum_{j=1}^nb_j^2).$$

This is a part of Exercise 1.1.5, and I am struggling with it. Can you give some hint?

Comment: That's [Lagrange's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: sums distributes over products.

> \begin{align}\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=1}^nb_j^2\Bigr)-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(a_ib_j - a_j b_i)^2&=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\sum_{j=1}^nb_j^2-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(a_i^2b_j^2 + a_j^2 b_i^2-2a_ia_jb_ib_j)\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_i^2b_j^2-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_i^2b_j^2-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_j^2 b_i^2+\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_ia_jb_ib_j\\&=\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\sum_{j=1}^na_jb_j\\&=\Bigl(\sum_{i=1}^na_ib_i\Bigr)^2\end{align}

Note that
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_i^2b_j^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\sum_{j=1}^nb_j^2\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^na_j^2\sum_{i=1}^nb_i^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_j^2b_i^2
\end{align}
by switching indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Could you explain how you go from the second to the third line?

Comment: @shk910: I added an explanation in the answer.